# How to create a start script for the example gRPC Java TLS server/client?

Tags: gradle, grpc-java

I'm trying to follow the the README.md for `grpc-java`'s TLS example, https://github.com/grpc/grpc-java/tree/master/examples/example-tls. It states that running

```
../gradlew installDist
```

> This creates the scripts `hello-world-tls-server`, `hello-world-tls-client`, in the `build/install/example-tls/bin/` directory that run the example. The example requires the server to be running before starting the client.

However, after replacing the gRPC version `1.36.0-SNAPSHOT` by `1.35.0` everywhere in the `examples` directory and running that command, the `build/install/examples/bin` directory contains no such scripts:

```
~/D/S/g/examples (master)> tree build/install/examples/bin
build/install/examples/bin
├── compressing-hello-world-client
├── compressing-hello-world-client.bat
├── hedging-hello-world-client
├── hedging-hello-world-client.bat
├── hedging-hello-world-server
├── hedging-hello-world-server.bat
├── hello-world-client
├── hello-world-client.bat
├── hello-world-server
├── hello-world-server.bat
├── retrying-hello-world-client
├── retrying-hello-world-client.bat
├── retrying-hello-world-server
├── retrying-hello-world-server.bat
├── route-guide-client
├── route-guide-client.bat
├── route-guide-server
└── route-guide-server.bat

0 directories, 18 files
```

In my local repository, I've changed this line, https://github.com/grpc/grpc-java/blob/1b23cf4f39ab26728336edbda8bb6af22dfe0a01/examples/example-tls/build.gradle#L58, to

```
startScripts.enabled = true
```

However, after running `./gradlew installDist` again, the expected start scripts are still nowhere to be found. I've perused the documentation on `CreateStartScripts`, https://docs.gradle.org/current/dsl/org.gradle.jvm.application.tasks.CreateStartScripts.html, but I don't immediately see what's amiss. Any idea why no start scripts are created for the TLS example?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The documentation [recommends](https://github.com/grpc/grpc-java/tree/v1.35.0/examples/example-tls) to checkout a git tag:

> You are strongly encouraged to check out a git release tag, since there will already be a build of grpc available

```
❯ git checkout v1.35.0
❯ cd examples/example-tls
❯ ../gradlew installDist
```

Then you'll be able to find the binaries in `build/install/example-tls/bin`:

```
❯ tree build/install/example-tls/bin
build/install/example-tls/bin
├── hello-world-tls-client
├── hello-world-tls-client.bat
├── hello-world-tls-server
└── hello-world-tls-server.bat
```